# Take the selected phone number [iPhone]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, abpersonviewcontroller

I'm trying to take phone number from the Contacts on the iPhone.
I implemented the

```
-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
```

from the **ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate**

In this method there is this code and it works:

```
NSString *firstName = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));
    NSLog(@"First Name ---> %@" ,firstName);

    NSString *secondName = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty));
    NSLog(@"Last name ---> %@" ,secondName);
```

but now I need to take also the phone number selected from the user. I have tried with this but it doesn't work for me:

```
NSString *numberSelected = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(person, property));
```

this give me a strange value like this:

```
ABMultiValueRef 0xa36e990 with 1 value(s)
    0: _$!<Mobile>!$_ (0xa36ee50) - (123) 456-7890 (0xa36ee70)
```

Then I tried with this but also this doesn't work:

```
ABMutableMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);
    CFStringRef phone = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multi, identifier);
    NSLog(@"Number Selected ---> %@" ,(NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(phone));
    CFRelease(phone);

    NSLog(@"Number Selected --> %@" ,numberSelected);
```

The string displayed is only:

```
_$!<Mobile>!$_
```

Now I don't know what to do... can you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with is  :

```
    CFStringRef cfnumber;
    ABMultiValueRef numbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty); 
    for(CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(numbers); i++) 
    {
        if(identifier == ABMultiValueGetIdentifierAtIndex (numbers, i)) 
        { 
            //if tapped number identifier is the same as identifier number tapped
            cfnumber = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(numbers, i); // copy the number to CFSTRING number
        }
    }        
    NSString *number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cfnumber];
    CFRelease(cfnumber);
```

Comment: But when I tap on a number, the "property" is that number. I don't need all the numbers that the users entered in the contacts, but only that one that was tapped.